# H2 Trigger crashes and destroy Database

Tags: java, sql, database, triggers, h2

I have a problem running a Trigger on my H2 Database.
The Trigger should cover 2 cases (INSERT and UPDATE) on a table.

The following 2 tables are involved in this process:

**Betellposition** (bestellnr (PK), bestellposnr (PK), artikelnr (FK), menge, summe)

and

**Artikel** (artikelnr (PK), bezeichnung, preis, artikelgrnr (FK))

The Trigger should calculate the sum (Summe) out of amount (Menge) * price (Preis)
if you are doing an INSERT or UPDATE (change the article (Artikel) or amount (Menge)) on Bestellposition.

Here is the code for the Trigger:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import org.h2.api.Trigger;

public class TriggerBestellpositionSumme implements Trigger {

@Override
public void close() throws SQLException {}

@Override
public void fire(Connection con, Object[] oldRow, Object[] newRow)
        throws SQLException {
    int neueBestellnr = 0;
    int neueBestellposnr = 0;
    int neueArtikelnr = 0;

    neueBestellnr = (int) newRow[0];
    neueBestellposnr = (int) newRow[1];
    neueArtikelnr = (int) newRow[2];

    PreparedStatement prep = con.prepareStatement           
            ("update bestellposition set summe = menge * "
                    + "(select artikel.preis from artikel where artikel.artikelnr = ?) "
                    + "where bestellnr = ? and bestellposnr = ?");
    prep.setInt(1, neueArtikelnr);
    prep.setInt(2, neueBestellnr);
    prep.setInt(3, neueBestellposnr);

    prep.execute();
}

@Override
public void init(Connection con, String schemaName, String triggerName, String tableName,
        boolean before, int type) throws SQLException {}

@Override
public void remove() throws SQLException {}

}
```

The INSERT just works fine.
There is only a problem with the UPDATE statement.
The functionality in the fire()-method must be the same for INSERT or UPDATE.

If I try to make an UPDATE on Bestellposition, it stops loading and i must terminate the application. After this, my database is destroyed.
Maybe this is a bug or something. I can´t figure out the problem.

I hope anyone could help me.

Edit: I have noticed that the size of the database file grows heavily during the UDPATE process and do not come to an end, like an endless loop!

Comment: So, inside an update (or insert) trigger, you again update the same table (and the same row)? Well, that will either get you an endless loop or endless recursion... Instead, you can change the data in the newRow array.

Comment: @ThomasMueller This sounds logical, thanks. Now I face a new Problem. How can I change the data in the newRow array ?! Something like this, do not work: newRow[3] = 12; And i find no method to set it.

Comment: What happens if you do it?

Comment: @ThomasMueller Nothing. With only the "newRow[3] = 12;" statement in the fire()-method, (register the trigger for INSERT and then) doing an INSERT in the table Bestellposition with sth like this "insert into bestellposition values (10016, 5, 1002, 12, 0);", the third row keeps its value 1002. Another question: Is this generally a case for using a trigger? Btw: It´s a great honour to get help from the originator of H2 database, so hopefully you could help me by solving this problem :)